# Найти произведение и сумму многочленов на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio

Найти сумму и произведение двух многочленов, заданных массивами своих коэффициентов (с суммой все ок, а с произведением проблемы):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[100] = {0};
    int size, n;
    int b[10] = {0} ;
    int len;
    int c[10] ;
    int p[10]  ;
    cin>>size;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    cin >> len;
    for (int j=0; j<len; j++)
        cin>>b[j];
    ///////////////СУММА
    if(size<=len)
        n = len;
    else
        n = size;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){             
                c[k] = a[k] + b[k];
                cout << c[k] <<" ";             
        }
    cout << endl;
    //////////////ПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЕ
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            p[i + j] += a[i]*b[j];

        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << p[i];

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что именно не так? Минимальный пример и тест есть?  Вангую размерность произведения массива должна быть как минимум сумма размеров множителей.

Comment: А вас компилятор не предупреждал о возможном использовании неинициализированной переменной?

Answer (score 1):

Все, нашла ошибку. Если кому интересно, то вот код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[100] = {0};
    int size, n;
    int b[10] = {0} ;
    int len;
    int c[10] ;
    int p[10] ={0} ;
    cin>>size;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    cin >> len;
    for (int j=0; j<len; j++)
        cin>>b[j];
    ///////////////СУММА
    if(size<=len)
        n = len;
    else
        n = size;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){             
                c[k] = a[k] + b[k];
                cout << c[k] <<" ";             
        }
    cout << endl;
    //////////////ПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЕ
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            p[i + j] += (a[i]*b[j]);

        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < (size + len -1); i++)
        cout << p[i] << endl;;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```